# Where are my packages custom module's tables in the database?

Tags: php, mysql, sugarcrm

using mysql with SugarCRM.

I have made a package and several custom modules to do some cool stuff.

I cannot see where the data is being saved. In mysql I cannot see any tables or any hints of any of my custom modules.

All of my modules were built using the basic module template.

I feel like the data is being stored in a hidden file somewhere that sugar knows about.

If this is the case, I want it in my DB.

Where is this being saved?

How can I continue to save it in the DB?

Did I forget to check something during installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tables in the SugarCRM database will be prefixed with the package key that you entered. So if your package name is "Dagron" and your package key is "dag" then look in the database for all tables starting with "dag_".

Comment: Im looking through the config.php and my settings look like this `dbconfig=>array (
    'db_host_name' => '192.168.5.123',
    'db_host_instance' => 'SQLEXPRESS',
    'db_user_name' => 'ffescrm',
    'db_password' => 'ffescrm1!',
    'db_name' => 'ffescrm',
    'db_type' => 'mysql',
    'db_port' => '',
    'db_manager' => 'MysqliManager',
  ),`
And that is not the settings i need them to be. however when i change them to the right table name and user and password the site doesnt come up. any ideas on recovering from here?

Comment: If your site is working with those settings then they are correct. That is the database (ffescrm) that it was installed on.

Comment: If you can find the custom module's core files, e.g. /modules/MyModule/MyModule.php - there is likely a $table_name variable that'll tell you exactly where the data lives. Probably something like `ffescrm.dag_mymodule`